# Cannot process the resultset in jsp

Tags: java, sql, jsp, resultset

I was trying to call a method in jsp which returns a resultSet. Like,

In JSP:

```
OracleResultSet rs = null;
rs = getMyValuesHere();
out.println("rs:"+rs); 
// rs is not null.Something like oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@1f1e1f
```

How can I retrieve my values here from the resultSet?
because not even entering into this while loop. ,

```
while(rs.next()) {

}
```

Method is:

```
<%!
public OracleResultSet getMyValuesHere()
{
    OracleConnection connection = null;
    OraclePreparedStatement ptmst = null;
    OracleResultSet rs = null;
    OracleCallableStatement cstmt = null;
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
    //My query goes here
    connection = (OracleConnection) TransactionScope.getConnection();
    sql.append("SELECT DISTINCT  something.... ");
    rs = (OracleResultSet)ptmst.executeQuery(); 
   return rs;
}
%>
```

I tried printing the data in `getMyValuesHere()`

```
rs = (OracleResultSet)ptmst.executeQuery();     
while (rs.next()) 
{
// rs.getString(1))  -- I was able to print this.
}
```

Comment: You should never access database from JSP, its a poor coding practice.

Comment: why are you using classes like `OracleConnection` instead of `Connection` and so on?

Comment: I assume your result is empty, I mean no data returned by your query execution.

Comment: May the result set is empty....
Don't use java code in jsp, now a days no client agree on this

Comment: Apart from the above comments, are you sure your query actually returns any data?

Comment: Yes, I tried printing in `getMyValuesHere()` and I was able to get the data correctly.

Comment: @log_in, update in your question with the code you tried to print it in `getMyValuesHere()` method.

Comment: Edited the question as you told. @PradeepSimha

Comment: didn't you say its not even entering the loop?

Comment: I know that you use an specific data base engine as Oracle and the library probably provides methods such OracleResultSet and so on, but it should be better if you work with the standard java.sql.* classes like ResultSet, PreparedStatement and Connection.

Comment: @Aashray: That is where I am trying to call the method..

Comment: executing your statement in the place where you actually need it and just creating a connection object so that it can be included everywhere is better practice. Try using `(OracleResultSet)ptmst.executeQuery();` where you actually need it.

Comment: @Aashray: I need resultSet in jsp to display the content. Where the result set is returning from another Java method.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified the Database Driver in your program.. Include the driver in your program and then try it once